# Is there a way to enter a variable (parameter) in a property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to give conditions to the C # Property included.

```
public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
{
    get
        {
            return context.Orders
                .Include("Member") //Member member
                .Include("OrderProducts"); //List<OrderProduct> OrderProducts
        }
}
```

This code using the entity framework actually matched the all orders in the database into the entity well.
and, Member table referenced in the Order table and the OrderProduct DB included in the order were collected well at once.

But since this code gather all Order's DB, I want to filter them by giving them a condition.

Of course making a method would be very simple, but I'm wondering if this is possible in property.
Is it possible to specify conditions through parameters to property?

Comment: A property is just magic sugar for a method with no parameters. If you're looking to add parameters ... you're essentially unrolling that syntactic sugar and writing a method.

Comment: Property is just like method, with some synatatic sugar.

Comment: Have you checked Linq?

Answer (score 4):

A property is just syntactic sugar to make basic methods easier to read and write. What this means, is that when its all compiled, it becomes a couple of methods.

For example, this:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

..is compiled to (something similar to) this:

```
private int _age;

public void set_Age(int age) {
    _age = age;
}

public int get_Age() {
    return _age;
}
```

For your specific question ... no. You can't pass parameters to the property.

Having said that.. you're returning an `IEnumerable<>` and the EF collections will play happily with deferred execution. So you can "filter" things at the callsite and it should be converted to the appropriate SQL:

```
yourObject.Orders.Where(x => x.Property == "Whatever").ToList();
```

Comment: hank you for the reply. I have one more question.  "yourObject.Orders.Where(x => x.Property == "Whatever").ToList();" When this condition is applied, does the query search the full searched data from the DB and then filter on that entire data? Or do filter only the reference data needed in the DB using the SQL JOIN statement?

Answer (score 3):

Giving property a parameter is impossible. You have to write your own method, if you want to pass the condition as a parameter. Like:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetFilteredOrders(Condition condition)
{
    // do filtering with condition
}
```

Of course you can stick to using property, like

```
private Condition _condition;

public IEnumerable<Order> FilteredOrders => Orders.Where(/* satisfies the _condition */);
```

And before calling this *property*, you have to set the `_condition` manually, like

```
_condition = // something you want to filter
```

Needless to say, I'd rather define a new method.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If you are okay, can you provide a specific example sentence for "private Condition _condition;" Thank you.

Comment: It was just a pseudo-code. It can be a string, enum, or whatever you want something to act as a filter. The main filter is the lambda or delegate in `Where()` function, and implementation is on your own. `private Condition _condition` is introduced instead of parameter, to hold the condition. You should prefer the method-way, since it would not work as you think, if you forget the setting of the condition before calling `FilteredOrders`.